# use multiple data source in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

There are 3 procedures. **One is having personal detail**, **Second is having business detail** and **third contains transaction done by person**. In `crystal report`, i want to use these procedures. Yes, in single report. Requirement is, display personal detail and business detail only on first page when person changes. display all transaction done by person. all 3 data sources contains person_id. Person detail, Business detail and transaction detail, then new page and repeat the same. This is what i want. I am using `Visual Studio 2008, C#, WEB_App, SQL-SERVER` with basic experience of crystal report. tried some sub-report and grouping but not getting what i want.
Need Help or Suggestion.
Thanks in Advance...!!

Comment: try to bring all data in single dataset using some join query based on person_id. and pass this dataset to Crystal Report.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i found the way to do this. I also did as you suggested for practice. It helped..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Adding all data sources with link on person_id. add grouping on basic detail of person_id. added sub report for business detail and set sub report link on person_id. below that added for transaction detail. removed data source of business detail from main report.
Thanks for View...!!